# How to access extjs controllers from console

Tags: javascript, extjs

It'd be super useful if I could access instances of my views and controllers in my ext.js application from Chrome's console. Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

---

*coffeescript:*

```
window.cms = Ext.create 'Ext.app.Application',
  name: 'CMS'
  controllers: [
    'MyController'
  ...
```

It would seem that `cms.getController('MyController')` would do what I want, but I get a constructor back instead of the instance I'm looking for.

Comment: Wow I haven't seen anybody write Ext-JS with CoffeScript. Can you post an image of what the console output looks like? Expanding a few properties on the object?

Comment: Just don't use those `getController` in your actual code. It makes for tightly coupled code. For debugging it's fine. Many people do it, but they don't care about reusability and testability)

Comment: I can't stand CoffeScript's syntax (to each their own) ... where are the braces? People say that braces are for computers, I guess I am a computer :) Also, you must have a heck of a hard time debugging your code.

Comment: Indeed, I really like it, but the debugging is a bit of a nightmare in this particular environment, and something I need to sort out. I'm not so sure about blaming coffee-script though since the main codebase I work on uses coffee-script as part of a SPAR (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/spar) app and in that context I get reasonable errors. So... I'm sorta tempted to blame Ext-JS... I mean, if I don't set things up exactly right, I often get no js errors at all, often something just won't render.

Comment: Ext-JS error messages could be better, they should consider adding a debug time check in all components in case you pass in the invalid config. But this has nothing to do with this problem, right? However, I've been coding more than 30% of my time on Ext-JS for about 5 years, so I don't worry about those things anymore :p However, you still have to map JS code to CoffeScript code when debugging, that's my biggest beef, besides the lack of braces :)

Comment: Yeah, the coffeescript to js thing doesn't bug me too much, but it could certainly be better. Honestly, right now bad configuration is probably taking up 95% of my time since I'm still trying to get used to the framework. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you get a constructor, it's just that chrome shows constructor when you call `console.log` on an Ext-JS object

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. Still, it doesn't have the methods on it that I defined in MyController. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried  `console.log( cms.getController('MyController').methodName)` ?

Comment: CORRECTION: it *does* have the methods... Chrome just wasn't listing them or autocompleting for me. Bonus points if you can explain that bit. But many thanks already.

Comment: re: `console.log...` — no, I hadn't. Leaning a bit too heavily on Chrome.

Comment: It didn't work because Chrome doesn't run methods (since they can have side effects) to do the autocomplete. Had you split it into two lines: `a = cms.getController('MyController');` Then typing `a.` should give you completion

Comment: Jackpot. That's actually exactly how I discovered that I had the correct object after all.

Comment: sorry guys, but where is cms object defined, should't it be CMS? oh - never mind I just noticed the window.cms reference.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create an application instance reference in the Application. Like this:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'CMS',
  controllers: ['MyController'],
  launch:function () {
     CMS.app = this;
     ...
  }
});
```

then you can use

CMS.app.getController('MyController') ...

Comment: Not true that OP needs to change their code. Also doesn't answer the question. The OP's code works fine. By the way, he's using CoffeScript, not JS. And actually Ext-JS already sets the `CMS` variable when you call `Ext.application` giving it a name of `'CMS'`

Comment: I see your point, however I think the difference is with the use of Ext.create vs Ext.application. The first must be creating an instance while the second creating a class definition. I can attest to the second scenario and the code I posted - because I ran into a similar issue.

Comment: `Ext.application` is just a wrapper that calls `new Ext.app.Application(config);` which is the same as calling  `Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', config)` assuming your dependencies are already loaded. `Ext.define` is the one that creates class definitions.

Comment: i just figured out it's the window.cms = that creates an app reference in OP's code! - But my opinion is that you are polluting the global space. The whole idea behind the App is that it's name is also your namespace. So I stand by my answer as the better way to create an app reference - if that's needed.

Comment: Except that the question is not about creating the app reference. So this is better suited as a comment: "Ext-JS already reference to the app as 'CMS', no need to create a second reference". However, I write my apps without ever needing to reference the application object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

`CMS.getApplication().controllers.get('ControllerName')`

then you will get the actual instance of the controller